# Haskell Text.CSV module

Tags: haskell

Why do I get type *Either Text.Parsec.Error.ParseError CSV* for the `parseCSV` function although in the documentation it says that output is *Either ParseError CSV*? I want to import a CSV file into Haskell and then export specific column from it and then compute statistics for that column.

I import a CSV file like:

```
data = parseCSV "/home/user/Haskell/data/data.csv"

noEmpRows = either (const []) (filter (\row -> 2 <= length row))

readIndex :: Read cell => Either a CSV -> Int -> [cell]

readIndex csv index = map (read . (!!index)) (noEmpRows csv)
```

and then I get an error when I want to `readIndex data 9 :: [Integer]`.

I've tried also a function `parseCSVFromFile`.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/csv-0.1.2/docs/Text-CSV.html#t:CSV

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: That `ParseError` is just a shortname for `Text.Parsec.Error.ParseError`. But your question is about the error, I presume? What does it say?

Comment: Couldn't match expected type ‘Either a0 CSV’
                  with actual type ‘String
                                    -> Either Text.Parsec.Error.ParseError CSV’

Comment: The type of `parseCSV` is `FilePath -> String -> Either ParseError CSV`, so the type of `data` (which isn't a valid identifier, so this code can't possibly compile) is `String -> Either ParseError CSV`, whereas the first argument of `readIndex` should have type `Either a CSV`.

Comment: I am new to Haskell, so what would be a final solution? Should I use a function parseCSVFromFile or how to rewrite the existing one? tnx

Answer (score 1):

The question you really seem to be asking is *How do I use Text.CSV?*

Given the file test.csv:

```
1,Banana,17
2,Apple,14
3,Pear,21
```

and this line in GHCi:

```
Prelude> Text.CSV.parseCSVFromFile "test.csv"
Right [["1","Banana","17"],["2","Apple","14"],["3","Pear","21"],[""]]
```

If you want to extract a column, then build a function for that:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  test_csv <- parseCSVFromFile "test.csv"
  case test_csv of
    Right csv -> print (extractColumn csv 2 :: [Int])
    Left err -> print err

extractColumn :: Read t => CSV -> Int -> [t]
extractColumn csv n =
  [ read (record !! n) | record <- csv
                       , length record > n
                       , record /= [""] ]
```

This should produce the output `[17,14,21]`.

Since there is ample room for failure here (a line could contain fewer fields than `n`, or the string in field `n` on a given line could fail to read as type *t*), you may want to handle or report if errors occur. The code above just throws away the line if it contains too few fields and throws a `Prelude.read: no parse` if the field isn't an *Int*. Consider [`readEither`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readEither) or [`readMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe).

Comment: I'd rename one of the two `csv` variables, to avoid shadowing which might confuse a human reader.

Comment: Thank you for Your help, I have only one more question, how can I save that output (IO) from main to let's say Integer and then apply sum function on that list?

Comment: @zoff Not quite sure, but it sounds like you need to understand more about the IO monad. Try reading up on it here: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io.html

Comment: @zoff: I've already separated `extractColumn` from the IO layer. You can similarly extend this function with e.g. `sum (extractColumn ...)` or any other calculation that assumes pure integer list input.

Comment: @SimonShine why do I get an error  ( Couldn't match type ‘Either Text.Parsec.Error.ParseError CSV’
                   with ‘[Record]’
    Expected type: CSV
      Actual type: Either Text.Parsec.Error.ParseError CSV ) when I run a command extractColumn csv' 2 :: [Integer] (I have saved csv' <- parseCSVFromFile "test.csv")

Comment: @zoff: StackOverflow is not a good platform for forth-and-back debugging. I suggest you put your code in a pastebin and go to the [freenode IRC #haskell channel](https://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=%23haskell) and ask. But basically: You're mixing up the variables `csv` and `csv'` just like @chi feared you might. Try `extractColumn csv 2` like the code says. The variable `test_csv` (was `csv'`) is *not* a *CSV* but an *Either ParseError CSV*. You first have to unwrap it.