# What's a good way to select a column from a CSV file in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to grab a column from a CSV file with a lot of columns (e.g. a few hundred), and while I've managed to write some code to do it using the Cassava package (aka `Data.Csv`) I'm not really happy with the result.  To wit:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BSL
import           Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 (unpack)
import qualified Data.Csv as CSV
import qualified Data.Vector as V    

-- | Read in the n'th column of a CSV file which has been read into a ByteString
readColumn :: Read a => Int -> CSV.HasHeader -> BSL.ByteString -> V.Vector a
readColumn index headerStatus csvData =
  let recs =
        CSV.decode headerStatus csvData :: Either String (V.Vector (V.Vector BSL.ByteString)) in
    case recs of
      Left err -> error err
      Right rows -> V.map (extractColumn index) rows
  where
    extractColumn :: Read c => Int -> V.Vector BSL.ByteString -> c
    extractColumn n = read . unpack . (V.! n)
```

Some parts of this are clunky and fragile (the parsing using `read` and `unpack`, and the sad excuse for error handling), but more generally I'm surprised that I had to write this at all - I'd have expected this to exist in the `Data.Csv` API and I'm wondering if it's there and I simply didn't recognize it, or if there's some other package I should have looked at.

Any suggestions on better ways to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be a possible duplicate of [Haskell Text.CSV module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49406019/haskell-text-csv-module). At least, the answer to the question reads a column from a CSV file in Haskell. There's quite a few CSV libraries with varying complexity; I believe one of the reasons why you don't see a rich API is because of the fragility of the CSV format: For example, you can't even be sure that a column is well-defined in all row intersections, and the desired behavior might be to have `Nothing` in those places or to skip them, depending on the use-case.

Comment: As you say - that looks like basically the same approach that I took (read in as strings, parse them to the desired type manually).  But thanks for pointing it out that solution - I was unaware of the Text.CSV module.

Comment: Why do you need only one column? You might be doing premature optimization. I've used cassava quite a bit and what I would do is  split the problem in two. The first to decode all the columns (using cassava) and the second to extract the column. Due to laziness the first step should actually only decode the column than you want.

Comment: @mb14 - One column is just where I got aggravated. :-)  I had a CSV file with about 200 columns and no headers, and I needed column 33 as `Int`s (and didn't care about any other columns).  I didn't want to write a record type with 200 fields or a `decode NoHeader bytes :: Either string (Vector (...200 element tuple type...)`.  I suppose I could have created a `newtype` for `Int` and written a `FromRecord` instance for it, but then I'd have to unwrap the newtype to get the `Int`s I wanted.  None of that felt like the right approach.  I feel like I'm missing something here in the cassava api...

Comment: You can use the index function (or .! operator) to access a column by index when defining a parser. You'll have to define back newtype for this but at least you dont have to do the read unpack by hands.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not suit your needs: It assumes that you're not actually interested in pulling out columns based on their position, but rather are interested in pulling out specific columns you are interested in.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
import           Data.Text    (Text)
import           Data.Vector
import           GHC.Generics

import           Data.Csv

data Foo
    = Foo
    { foo :: Text
    , bar :: Int
    } deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)
instance FromNamedRecord Foo

decodeFoo :: _ -> Either String (Header, Vector Foo)
decodeFoo = decodeByName

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let csv = "bar,ignore,foo,ignore\n3,whatever,some string,whatever"
    print $ decodeFoo csv
    -- prints Right (["bar","ignore","foo","ignore"],[Foo {foo = "some string", bar = 3}])
```

Comment: That's interesting - I didn't realize that `decodeByName` supported partial decoding in this way.  It does involve a bit of ceremony in the form of a new data type, but that's not so bad.  I guess what I was really looking for (in the with-headers case) was something like `decodeColumn csv "bar" :: Either String (Header, Vector Int)` without the need to create a new record type.  But this looks nice.

Comment: It also doesn't work with user inputted column names because you can't create the record in advance

Answer (score 0):

Following your comment about FromRecord. cassava is typeclass based, so unless you are decoding a combination of basic types you have unfortunately to provide a typeclass instance and therefore a Newtype. There is no option than I am aware of which take a parsing function (which would be useful anyway). My experience is that type are cheap (almost free) in Haskell and it's common to create disposable type when needed.  If you need 33 out of the 100 columns just create a data type for those fields and write your instance for it. You can then pick and choose which column you actually need. You might then realize than you don't want Int but (Either Text Int) (to be able to display the field in case of error) and parametrised your whole record via a functor.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks.